# regex for comma followed by space or just comma

Tags: javascript, regex

is it possible to make a regex with multiple delimiters? For example I want to split a string which can come in two forms: 1. "string1, string2, string3" or 2. "string1,string2,string3". I've been trying to do this in javascript but with no success so far.

Comment: How about `,\s|,` ? It will match only one space.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just use a regex `split()`:

```
var string = "part1,part2, part3, part4,    part5",
    components = string.split(/,\s*/);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tUkua/).

The reason I've used `*` rather than `?` is simply because it allows for no white-space or many white-spaces. Whereas the `?` matches zero-or-one white-space (which is exactly what you asked, but even so).

Incidentally, if there might possibly be white-spaces preceding the comma, then it might be worth amending the `split()` regex to:

```
var string = "part1,part2  , part3, part4,    part5",
    components = string.split(/\s*,\s*/);
console.log(components);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tUkua/1/).

Which splits the supplied string on zero-or-more whitespace followed by a comma followed by zero-or-more white-space. This may, of course, be entirely unnecessary.

References:

- [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`string.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: @DanielV :: +1 :: This solution is the one that should be accepted, as input string can be for example `string1,    string2,  string3,   string4,    string5` and Silva's code would not make it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, make the whitespace (`\s`) optional using `?`:

```
var s = "string1,string2,string3";
s.split(/,\s?/);
```

Comment: works great, thanks. i will accept the answer as soon as it allows me to

Answer (score 1):

In addition to silva

just in case you have doubt it can have more than one space then use (or no space)

```
var s = "string1, string2,  string3";
s.split(/,\s*/);
```